# Youtube Data API - Java implementation

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api, google-api-java-client

Been browsing for a while but can't find concrete answer whether the Java implementation of the Youtube Data API includes handling rate limits out of the box or is this something one has to account for?

https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-java-client-services/tree/main/clients/google-api-services-youtube/v3

Reading the documentation - hoped to find actual specific section about this but couldn't find.

Comment: As far as I know these libraries don't handle rate limits, but I may be wrong on this one, so it's up to you to handle the rate limits as you wish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I recall all of the google apis client libraries have exponential backoff functionality built in.  You need to look in the main library not the package for the individual apis

If you do a [search](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-java-client/search?q=exponential+backoff&type=) in the code you can even see there is a build option for it.

It won't hurt to add your own rate limiting on top of this.   You need to check exactly what errors they are catching.  For example I don't think the retry all of the quote errors they could.   I normally add that myself if it becomes an issue in my application.